# Template definition order problem

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++11

I've got a simple mixin, which I am mixing in to my other template classes.

```
template<typename T> class mixin {
    static T* null() { return nullptr; }
    auto func() -> decltype(null()->func());
};
template<...> class A : public mixin<A<...>> {
    ....
};
template<...> class B : public mixin<A<...>> {
    ....
};
template<...> class C : public mixin<A<...>> {
    ....
};
```

Now, I've got a problem. One of the mixin functions will return a type which must be deduced depending on the derived type. But when I attempt to use deduction to find this type, the compiler tells me that I am using an undefined type. If I move the definition of `mixin` to be after the classes, then I won't be able to inherit from it when mixing in. How can I change my classes to allow type deduction in this case?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `auto func() -> ...` instead of `void`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's any way to make this work. You have a cyclic dependency between the types of each class. `A` needs the definition of `mixin<A<...>>` and `mixin<A<...>>` needs the definition of `A`.

In my opinion, you would be best just to manually specify the type in the mixin parameters.

For example:

```
template<typename ReturnType> class mixin
{
    auto func() -> ReturnType;
};

template<...> class A : public mixin<int>
{
    int func();
};
```